# Creating an typed async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I want to create some async Tasks without starting them at the moment.
With the untyped Tasks there is no problem:

```
    private Task CreateTask() {
        return new Task(
             async () => await DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
```

But to handle Exceptions I added a return value to my function. But how can I write it in a correct syntax:

```
    private Task<bool> CreateTask() {
        return new Task<bool>(
            async () =>  await DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
```

I get the message, that the async lambda expression can't be converted to func.
So my question: How is it written correctly?

Comment: Both methods are wrong. `DoSomething()` already returns a running Task so you can just return it as-is, `return (Task)DoSomething();`. `await` *awaits* for an already running task to complete, it doesn't make it start asynchronously. There's no reason to create a cold task with `new`. In the second case, what is the value supposed to be?

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X, think that Y is the solution and ask about Y when it doesn't work. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: To handle exceptions enclose your `await ` call with an exception handler, just as you would with a synchronous method. `await` will cause the original exception to be thrown. You could write eg `try{ .... await CallMyServerAsync();}catch(WebException exc){...}` just as you would write `try{ .... await CallMyServer();}catch(WebException exc){...}` if `CallMyServer` is a blocking method

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create some async Tasks without starting them at the moment.

That is the wrong solution for whatever problem you're trying to solve. If you want to define code that you want to run in the future, then you should use a delegate:

```
private Func<Task> CreateTaskFactory()
{
  return async () => await DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

> But to handle Exceptions I added a return value to my function.

Again, that's not the best solution. Tasks already understand exceptions just fine without writing any additional code.

If you *do* need to return a value (as *data*), then you can return a delegate that creates a `Task<T>`:

```
private Func<Task<int>> CreateTaskFactory()
{
  return async () => await DoSomethingReturningInt().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: `CreateTaskFactory` can just be `return DoSomething();`  There's no advantage to an `async` delegate here.

Comment: @Servy: I'm assuming that the op wants to define the operation now, but start it at a later time.

Comment: Sorry, meant `return () => DoSomething();`

Comment: @Servy: Oh, yeah. Absolutely, unless the op's delegates are not trivial.

Comment: Sure, although if it's non-trivial enough it would most likely best be refactored out into a named method.